# Does covenant rank progression reset on starting a new game cycle?

Tags: dark-souls-3

I've been playing offline and decided to start the long and arduous grind for the various spells and rings associated with covenants. I decided to cash in on a few once I got ten of each of some of the covenant items. However, all this repetitive slaying of the same enemies is wearing on my sanity, but I'm not sure if my covenant rank progression carries over to new game +. Does it carry over my rank? Does it carry over the exact amount of items I've offered?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Covenant rank progression carries over to new game according to the [Dark Souls 3 Wiki](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/New+Game+Plus)

> What carries over to New Game Plus:
>
> - **Covenant allegiance.**
> - All your consumables, armor, weapons, equipment, stats, INCLUDING    coiled sword fragment.
> - Estus and bonfire updates.
> - Hollowing.
> - Friendship with Giant of the Undead Settlement (his arrows won't hurt    the player, only enemies, without talking to him) as long as
>     you keep    "his" white birch branch
>
> *On other various forum's, users have confirmed that Covenant Progress is caried over in NG+

Comment: Was about to ask if covenant allegiance was the rank or the items, but I remembered the phrase is "Covenant allegiance deepened" when offering an item. Thanks for the speedy response!